# Select rows from a table which contains at-least one alphabet in the column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have column called `name` under a table in Databricks.

I want to find a way to select only those rows from a table, which contains at-least one alphabet character in the `name` column.

Example values in the column:

```text
12243
#123-(23)
$ank
ada124$%
()
!asd
122acs#
gmgd32
```

Expected: I need to pick only those values which contains at least one alphabet in it. Or in other words, I need a way to exclude all the rows which contains only numbers and special characters.

So the Expected output should be as below :

```text
$ank
ada124$%
!asd
122acs#
gmgd32
```

because these contains at least one alphabet in them.

I am using pyspark-sql in data bricks.

Comment: Unable to test but a quick Google suggests you can use `like '%[A-z]%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rlike` with regex:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.filter(F.col("name").rlike(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*")).show()

#+--------+
#|    name|
#+--------+
#|    $ank|
#|ada124$%|
#|    !asd|
#| 122acs#|
#|  gmgd32|
#+--------+
```

Spark SQL equivalent query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   df
WHERE  name RLIKE '.*[a-zA-Z]+.*'
```

Comment: With the risk of sounding pedantic, the `+` is not needed